# Ridpath's Boethius translation

Tags: early-modern-english

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I'll do it anyway. I am a student from Austria and one of our professors has given us a task which seems rather demanding. He wants us to analyze English in history/change on the example of Ridpath's Boethius translation from 1785 in a proseminar paper.

The problem is I can't get my hands on a text that has been written a little earlier (e.g., Johnson's Boethius translation) to compare them, but only on a text that has been written very much earlier by Queen Elizabeth. And no, I can't ask him for help, he's a confusing, kind of mean guy, who keeps telling us he expects students to be able to organize themselves.

Thanks in advance for helpful advice.

Answer (score 1):

A scan of Morris' 1868 EETS edition of Chaucer's Middle English translation is available [here](https://ia800301.us.archive.org/26/items/chaucerstransla00boetgoog/chaucerstransla00boetgoog.pdf), and that edition is transcribed [here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=cme;cc=cme;view=toc;idno=ChaucerBo).

A scan of Elizabeth I's Early Modern English translation is available [here](https://ia801300.us.archive.org/32/items/queenelizabethse00eliz/queenelizabethse00eliz.pdf).

[This dissertation](http://uknowledge.uky.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1567&context=gradschool_diss) on three early versions (Alfred's, Chaucer's, Elizabeth's) includes an appendix listing English translations. Of those before your man Ridpath I have been able to find only one online: a 1674 partial translation by Edmund Elys transcribed [here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A28549.0001.001?view=toc).
Others are John Bracegirdle (1602) 'I.T.' (?John Thorpe? 1609), Harry Coningsby (1664), H__ Duke of ___ (1693), Richard Preston (1695), William Causton (1730). All of these are 'prosimetric' versions; the dissertation and its bibliographic apparatus will give you more details of editions if you are interested in any of them.

Johnson did not translate the *Consolations*.